# selecting group

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model  a mouthful of teeth.  I started with a basic tooth shape, i'm in edit mode and I'm trying to find a way that lets you select individual shapes within that group.  anyone know that one?

Comment: your question is not precise enough, maybe what you need is L to select a mesh among others?

Comment: Press L and the group gets selected

Answer (score 0):

you can hover with the mouse over your tooth and press <kbd>L</kbd>, or select a vertex, edge or face of the tooth and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

This will select all the vertex that are connected together